# install robot 3t :- usr/local/bin/robomongo/lib’: Directory not empty

Tags: 14.04, database, mongodb

I am trying to install robo3t in ubuntu 14.04 new in linux

Those commands work

```
wget https://download.robomongo.org/0.9.0/linux/robomongo-0.9.0-linux-x86_64-0786489.tar.gz
tar -xvzf robomongo-0.9.0-linux-x86_64-0786489.tar.gz
sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin/robomongo
```

But when I write this command

```
sudo mv  robomongo-0.9.0-linux-x86_64-0786489/* /usr/local/bin/robomongo
```

I get

> ```
> error :- /usr/local/bin/robomongo/lib’: Directory not empty
> ```

Comment: `sudo mv  robomongo-0.9.0-linux-x86_64-0786489/* /usr/local/bin/robomongo` you can't move contents of a directory to overwrite a directory as a file. You are (at minimum) missing a `/` at the end.

Comment: i am also trying removing deirectory and install it agian but faild

Comment: Looks like you have tried to install previously...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following;

1. Download archive with RoboMongo

   ```
   wget https://download.robomongo.org/0.9.0/linux/robomongo-0.9.0-linux-x86_64-0786489.tar.gz
   ```
2. Extract it

   ```
   tar -xvzf robomongo-0.9.0-linux-x86_64-0786489.tar.gz
   ```
3. Copy its contents with `cp -a` (`a` is for recursive archival copy) to `/usr/local`

   ```
   sudo cp -a robomongo-0.9.0-linux-x86_64-0786489/* /usr/local/
   ```
4. Remove extracted RoboMongo directory:

   ```
   rm -rf robomongo-0.9.0-linux-x86_64-0786489/*
   ```

And then launch RoboMongo with `robomongo`.

But the method which you are trying to use will trash your `/usr/local`.

Comment: not working same issue `Not a directory`